# What is `objc_msgSend_fixup`, exactly?

Tags: objective-c, assembly, segmentation-fault, objective-c-runtime

I'm messing around with the Objective-C runtime, trying to compile objective-c code without linking it against `libobjc`, and I'm having some segmentation fault problems with a program, so I generated an assembly file from it. I think it's not necessary to show the whole assembly file. At some point of my `main` function, I've got the following line (which, by the way, is the line after which I get the seg fault):

```
callq   *l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc
```

and here is the definition for `l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc`:

```
.hidden l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc # @"\01l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc"
    .type   l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc,@object
    .section    "__DATA, __objc_msgrefs, coalesced","aw",@progbits
    .weak   l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc
    .align  16
l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc:
    .quad   objc_msgSend_fixup
    .quad   L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_
    .size   l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc, 16
```

I've reimplemented `objc_msgSend_fixup` as a function (`id objc_msgSend_fixup(id self, SEL op, ...)`) which returns `nil` (just to see what happens), but this function isn't even being called (the program crashes before calling it).

So, my question is, what is `callq *l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc` supposed to do and what is `objc_msgSend_fixup` (after `l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc:`) supposed to be (a function or an object)?

**Edit**

To better explain, I'm not linking my source file against the objc library. What I'm trying to do is implement some parts of the libray, just to see how it works. Here is an approach of what I've done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <objc/runtime.h>

@interface MyClass {

}
+(id) alloc;
@end

@implementation MyClass
+(id) alloc {
  // alloc the object
  return nil;
}
@end

id objc_msgSend_fixup(id self, SEL op, ...) {
  printf("Calling objc_msgSend_fixup()...\n");

  // looks for the method implementation for SEL in self's method list

  return nil;   // Since this is just a test, this function doesn't need to do that
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MyClass *m;
    m = [MyClass alloc];    // At this point, according to the assembly code generated
    // objc_msgSend_fixup should be called. So, the program should, at least, print
    // "Calling objc_msgSend_fixup()..." on the screen, but it crashes before
    // objc_msgSend_fixup() is called...

    return 0;
}
```

If the runtime needs to access the object's vtable or the method list of the obect's class to find the correct method to call, what is the function which actually does this? I think it is `objc_msgSend_fixup`, in this case. So, when `objc_msgSend_fixup` is called, it receives an object as one of its parameters, and, if this object hasn't been initialized, the function fails.

So, I've implemented my own version of `objc_msgSend_fixup`. According to the assembly source above, it should be called. It doesn't matter if the function is actually looking for the implementation of the selector passed as parameter. I just want `objc_msgSend_lookup` to be called. But, it's not being called, that is, the function that looks for the object's data is not even being called, instead of being called and cause a fault (because it returns a `nil` (which, by the way, doesn't matter)). The program seg fails before `objc_msgSend_lookup` is called...

**Edit 2**

A more complete assembly snippet:

```
.globl  main
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main
.Ltmp20:
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
.Ltmp21:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.Ltmp22:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
.Ltmp23:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movl    $0, %eax
    leaq    l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc, %rcx
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %edi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    movq    L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_, %rsi
    movq    %rsi, %rdi
    movq    %rcx, %rsi
    movl    %eax, -28(%rbp)         # 4-byte Spill
    callq   *l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
    movl    -28(%rbp), %eax         # 4-byte Reload
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

For `l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc`, we have:

```
.hidden l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc # @"\01l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc"
    .type   l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc,@object
    .section    "__DATA, __objc_msgrefs, coalesced","aw",@progbits
    .weak   l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc
    .align  16
l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc:
    .quad   objc_msgSend_fixup
    .quad   L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_
    .size   l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc, 16
```

For `L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_`:

```
.type   L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_,@object # @"\01L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_"
    .section    "__DATA, __objc_classrefs, regular, no_dead_strip","aw",@progbits
    .align  8
L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_:
    .quad   OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass
    .size   L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_, 8
```

`OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass` is a pointer to the `MyClass` struct definition, which has been also generated by the compiler and it's also present in the assembly code.

Comment: This is Objective-C, not C. Re-tagging.

Comment: +1 because even though it wasn't my problem, it pushed me to learn something new

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but can you also provide the assembly output of the crash? Something like 10 or 20 lines before the actual segfault?

Comment: See the edit 3 at the bottom on my post...

Comment: Hey, guys, I just found out something interesting. If I put the objc_msgSend_fixup definition inside the main file (just like I did in one of the code snippets above), the function is called and prints that message, like I want it to do. But I actually put the definition of objc_msgSend_fixup in another file which is linked with the main file. This way, my main executable file seems not to be finding the function address. I'm gonna try to make some changes. It seems to be really a linking problem...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To understand what `objc_msgSend_fixup` is and what it does it's necessary to know exactly how message sending is performed in Objective-C. All the ObjC programmers have heard one day that the compiler transforms `[obj message]` statements into `objc_msgSend(obj, sel_registerName("message"))` calls. However, that's not entirely accurate.

To better ilustrate my explanation, consider the following ObjC snippet:

```
[obj mesgA];
[obj mesgB];

[obj mesgA];
[obj mesgB];
```

In this snippet, two messages are sent to `obj`, each of which is sent twice. So, you might imagine that the following code is generated:

```
objc_msgSend(obj, sel_registerName("mesgA"));
objc_msgSend(obj, sel_registerName("mesgB"));
objc_msgSend(obj, sel_registerName("mesgA"));
objc_msgSend(obj, sel_registerName("mesgB"));
```

However `sel_registerName` may be too costly and call it whenever a specific method is called is not a smart thing to do. Then, the compiler generates structures like this for each message to be sent:

```
typedef struct message_ref {
    id (*trampoline) (id obj, struct message_ref *ref, ...);
    union {
        const char *str;
        SEL sel;
    };
} message_ref;
```

So, in the example above, when the program starts, we have something like this:

```
message_ref l_objc_msgSend_fixup_mesgA = { &objc_msgSend_fixup, "mesgA" };
message_ref l_objc_msgSend_fixup_mesgB = { &objc_msgSend_fixup, "mesgB" };
```

When these messages need to be sent to `obj`, the compiler generates code equivalent to the following:

```
l_objc_msgSend_fixup_mesgA.trampoline(obj, &l_objc_msgSend_fixup_mesgA, ...);   // [obj mesgA];
l_objc_msgSend_fixup_mesgB.trampoline(obj, &l_objc_msgSend_fixup_mesgB, ...);   // [obj mesgB];
```

At the program startup, the message reference trampolines are pointers to the `objc_msgSend_fixup` function. For each `message_ref`, when its `trampoline` pointer is invoked for the first time, `objc_msgSend_fixup` gets called receiving the `obj` to which the message's got to be sent and the `message_ref` structure from which it was called. So, what `objc_msgSend_fixup` must do is get the selector for the message to be called. Since, this has to be done only once for each message reference, `objc_msgSend_fixup` must also replace the `trampoline` field of the ref by a pointer to another function that doesn't fix the message's selector. This function is called `objc_msgSend_fixedup` (the selector has been fixed up). Now that the message selector has been set and this doesn't have to be done again, `objc_msgSend_fixup` just calls `objc_msgSend_fixedup` and this just calls `objc_msgSend`. After that, if a message ref's `trampoline` is called again, its selector is already fixed, and `objc_msgSend_fixedup` is the one that gets called.

In short, we could write `objc_msgSend_fixup` and `objc_msgSend_fixedup` like this:

```
id objc_msgSend_fixup(id obj, struct message_ref *ref, ...) {
    ref->sel = sel_registerName(ref->str);
    ref->trampoline = &objc_msgSend_fixedup;
    objc_msgSend_fixedup(obj, ref, ...);
}

id objc_msgSend_fixedup(id obj, struct message_ref *ref, ...) {
    objc_msgSend(obj, ref->sel, ...);
}
```

This makes message sending a lot faster, since the appropriate selector is discovered only at the first time the message is called (by `objc_msgSend_fixup`). On later calls, the selector will have been already found and the message is called directly with `objc_msgSend` (by `objc_msgSend_fixedup`).

In the question's assembly code, `l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc` is the `alloc` method's `message_ref` structure and the segmentation fault may have been caused by a problem in its first field (maybe it's not pointing to `objc_msgSend_fixup`...)

Comment: This is a really well put answer, and a really cool optimization to see in code instead of the assembler!

Answer (score 7):

Ok, your code is Objective-C, not C.

**Edit / About objc_msgSend_fixup**

`objc_msgSend_fixup` is internal Objective-C runtime stuff, used to manage calls using a C++ style method vtable.

You may read some articles about this here:

- http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.ch/2010/01/understanding-objective-c-runtime.html
- http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/

**Edit / End**

Now about your segfault.

Objective-C uses a runtime for message passing, allocations, etc.

Message passing (method call) is usually done by the `objc_msgSend` function.
That's what is used when you do:

```
[ someObject someFunction: someArg ];
```

It's translated to:

```
objc_msgSend( someObject, @selector( someFunction ), someArg );
```

So if you have a segfault in such a runtime function, such as `objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc`, **it certainly means you calling a method on an uninitialized pointer (if not using ARC), or on a freed object.**

Something like:

```
NSObject * o;

[ o retain ]; // Will segfault somewhere in the Obj-C runtime in non ARC, as 'o' may point to anything.
```

Or:

```
NSObject * o;

o = [ [ NSObject alloc ] init ];

[ o release ];
[ o retain ]; // Will segfault somewhere in the Obj-C runtime as 'o' is no longer a valid object address.
```

**So even if the segfault location is in the runtime, this is certainly a basic Objective-C memory management issue, in your own code.**

Try enabling NSZombie, it should help.
Also try the static analyzer.

**Edit 2**

It's crashing in the runtime, because the runtime needs to access the object's vtable to find the correct method to call.

As the object is invalid, the vtable lookup results in the dereference of an invalid pointer.

This is why the segfault is located here.

**Edit 3**

You say you're not linked with the objc library.
What do you call the «objc library»?

I'm asking this because, as we can see in your code, you are definitively using an Objective-C compiler.

You may not link with the «Foundation» framework, for instance, which provides the base objects, but since you're using an Objective-C compiler, the **libobjc** library (providing the runtime) will still be implicitly linked.

Are you sure it's not the case? Try a simple `nm` on your resulting binary.

**Edit 4**

If this is really the case, the `objc_msgSend_fixup` is not the first function to do in order to recreate the runtime.

As you define a class, the runtime needs to know about it, so you need to code stuff like `objc_allocateClassPair` and friends.

You'll also need to ensure the compiler won't use shortcuts.

I've seen in you're code stuff like: `L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_`.

Does this symbol exist in your own version?

Comment: Ok. But the point is, the function which is being called is `objc_msgSend_fixup`, not `objc_msgSend()`. Besides this, the referred function seems not even to be called. So, if it were a problem caused by an uninitialized object, the function would be called and the seg fault would occur inside it (I guess), which is not what it's happening...

Comment: Please read the edit about objc_msgSend_fixup, at top, and the second edit at the end.

Comment: For an Objective-C method, the function pointer must be found on the object before it's actually called. If the object is invalid, the method lookup will segfault, way ahead the actual method call.

Comment: Yes, but if the runtime needs to access the object's vtable to find the correct method to call, what is the function which actually does this? I think it is `objc_msgSend` (and `objc_msgSend_fixup`). So, when `objc_msgSend` is called, it receives an object as one of its parameters, and, if this object hasn't been initialized, the function fails. But the point is, the function that looks for the object's data is not even being called, instead of being called and fail when it notes that the object hasn't being initialized. So, it's a lower level problem.

Comment: To find methods on an object, the runtime must retrieve the class object from the object, usually through the `isa` pointer. So it may also fail here, before the method lookup. Why haven't you posted the code **before** the segfault, so we can see?

Comment: I'm not linking my source file against the libobjc. What I'm trying to do is implement some parts of the libray, just to see how it works. So, I've implemented my own version of `objc_msgSend_fixup`. According to the assembly source above, it should be called. It doesn't matter if the function is actually looking for the implementation of the selector passed as parameter. I just want `objc_msgSend_lookup` to be called. But, it's not being called. The program seg fails before `objc_msgSend_lookup` is called.

Comment: For **edit 3**, yes, I'm using an obj-c compiler. But the compiler transforms some objective-c specific statements into function calls and data structures. As yourself has said, `[someObject someFunction: someArg]` is translated to `objc_msgSend(someObject, @selector(someFunction), someArg)`, for example. So, it's necessary to link the file against `libobjc.A.dylib`, so that the linker can find the references to functions like `objc_msgSend` and `objc_msgSend_fixup`. I'm just not linking it against `libobjc.A.dylib`, since I'm trying to implement my small own version of this library.

Comment: Yes, but then, do you have fully rebuilt the runtime functions for registering and querying classes? Does your version provides a way to retrieve existing classes, such as your `MyClass`?

Comment: Check my question again. I've done another edit at the end of it.

Comment: Ok, so now where's the exact location of the segfault, in your assembler dump?