# What is a fixed up method list in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

I'm reading objc/runtime source code. I noticed there are fixedUp getter and setter in `struct method_list_t`. What does that mean?

[image]

Edit 1:

I have read the 2 answers to the question [What is `objc_msgSend_fixup`, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228350/what-is-objc-msgsend-fixup-exactly). I don't think these have answered my question because they did't explain what `fix_up` really means.

Edit 2:

Here is the source code I was reading. https://github.com/xdxu1126/objc4

The struct mentioned (`struct method_list_t`) is located at FILE `objc-runtime-new.h` LINE 586.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is \`objc\_msgSend\_fixup\`, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228350/what-is-objc-msgsend-fixup-exactly)

Comment: @zrzka Not really. I think the 2 answers to the suggested question didn't explain what does `fix_up` mean.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source code you were reading?

Comment: @Cristik Sure. will update it in the description.

Answer (score -3):

```
static uint32_t fixed_up_method_list = 3;
```

fix_up mean is equal 3

3 = (alloc + init + currentMethod)

**this is my own idea**